# Reverse lookup of foreign key in python django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have 2 tables Dept and Employee

```
Dept has 2 columns ID and Name
Employees has 3 columns ID, Dept_ID, Name
```

Now given a emloyee name "XYZ" I have to retrieve all the department names having an employee with name "XYZ"

I know their is a work around for this by first retrieving all dept_id `having name == "XYZ"` from Employee table and then make another query for retrieving names of departments from Dept Table.

Is their a way to retrieve the records in a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return Dept.objects.filter(employees_set__name='XYZ')
```

Should do the job.

Answer (score 7):

I highly recommend to use "related_name" for all your foreign keys:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, related_name='employees')
```

then you can do:

```
dept = Dept.objects.get(id=10)
for employee in dept.employees.all():
    ...
```

and for the query you are asking about:

```
Dept.objects.filter(employees__name='XYZ')
```

---

That's really useful to add more meaningful names as well. In this case it's not a big deal (just dropping 'set') but it's really useful for relations for the User table for instance...